# dnsmasq + systemd-resolved high cpu

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

I'm using DNSMasq only for DNS caching, other DNS queries should go to the original DNS configured in systemd-resolved (if I understand the flow correctly).
All the solutions to this issue are saying to disable the systemd-resolved stub listened but I do need it as DNSMasq is using it as last resort for records it didn't match:

[image]

If DNSMasq don't know how to resolve an address, it asks systemd-resolved listening on 127.0.0.53:53 and then it goes to the external DNS server.

[image]

Anything I can do to lower the CPU without disabling  systemd-resolved?

Comment: I think the problem is that dnsmasq and systemd-resolved are both sending requests to each other to attempt to resolve DNS which results in an infinite loop. However, I haven't been able to figure out a good solution to this yet.